# What does "thrashing about" mean?

Tags: translation

In an ROBERT LOWELL's interview, in interviewer's question, I don't get the meaning of the part.

Also in LOWELL's answer I dont get the part in italic, could any one help me to understand?

- INTERVIEWER
             But something of Crane does seem to have gotten into your work—or maybe it’s just that ***sence of power thrashing about***. I
  thought it had come from a close admiring reading of Crane.

  LOWELL
             Yes, ***some kind of wildness and power that appeals to me,*** I guess. But when I wrote difficult poems they weren’t meant
  to be difficult, though I don’t know that Crane meant his to be. I
  wanted to be loaded and rich, but I thought the poems were all
  perfectly logical. You can have a wonderful time explaining a great
  poem like “Voyages II,” and it all can be explained, but in the end
  it’s just a love poem with a great confusion of images that are
  emotionally clear; a prose paraphrase wouldn’t give you any
  impression whatever of the poem. I couldn’t do that kind of poem, I
  don’t think; at least I’ve never been able to.

Here is the link of interview: 
       https://www.theparisreview.org/interviews/4664/robert-lowell-the-art-of-poetry-no-3-robert-lowell

Comment: It's not *[power thrashing]*, it's a *[sense of power]* which is *[thrashing about]*.

Comment: I took it to be *sense of [power thrashing about]*, that is, a feeling that something powerful was moving wildly.  It's the power that is thrashing, not the sense.    The *sense* is the feeling the reader gets from the work, although we often see phrases like "In Faulkner, there's this sense of ....." as if the sense were a quality of the work rather than a feeling created by the work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @choster points out the phrasing is

> *power* thrashing about

thrashing about means to move wildly

The comment

> some kind of wildness and power that *appeals to me*

*appeals to me* means the person finds it attractive, that they like it

If someone says

> It is appealing to me.

it means they *like* or are *attracted to* something.

> A cold beer sounds very appealing on a hot summer day.

Comment: Thanks alot. Could u tell about apeals to me ,here?